# Front-end AngularJS alternative library for an existing SSR (Server-side Rendering) Apps using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

Since AngularJS is no longer have public maintenance and support, is there any new front-end library alternative to AngularJS for an existing SSR (Server-side Rendering) Apps using ASP.NET Core MVC? I need similar several functionalities such as MVVM templating and basic utils like AJAX calls etc, but without changing the server-side code.

Comment: There's Blazor.  But if you are using a Single Page Application, why, oh why, use server-side rendering?

Comment: I am not using SPA, it is an ASP.NET Core MVC app, so it is SSR or MPA. AngularJS MVVM is easier to use than using jQuery only for UI manipulation. That is why I need an MVVM alternative to AngularJS that includes AJAX calls functionality and Client-Side Form Validation.

Comment: Blazor is SPA and it requires me to revamp the entire MVC app.

Comment: The reason I need to retain ASP.NET MVC is SEO friendly. Those SPA is difficult to get SEO to work.

Comment: Blazor has a "Prerender" mode that I think would work for your needs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#prerendering  If you don't want to go that route, I'd just make it a standard ASP.NET MVC type app.  Use standard Javascript or jQuery for things that wouldn't effect SEO.  (most of that concern is about share URLs... you can deal with that separately and still have an SPA running client-side, but that is more work.) All major search engines crawl SPAs just fine.  It's aggregators that can sometimes have issues.

Comment: There's also an answer in this thread that provides SSR for React: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379780/asp-net-core-3-1-with-react-server-side-rendering-pre-rendering-two-web-se

Comment: Thank you for your input. Let me check Blazor, but the thing with Blazor is it requires a stable internet connection, is that right?

Comment: I believe you can build complete off-line apps with Blazor, so no.